# MeasureString always thinks whitespace will fit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, gdi

I'm trying to do some hit testing on strings (I want to get the char index from the x offset), but I'm hitting issues with measure string.

This is essentially the code I am using

```
     StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap | StringFormatFlags.LineLimit);
     e.Graphics.MeasureString("test    string", this.Font, new SizeF(xHitTestPosition, this.Font.Height), sf, out charFitted, out linesFilled);
```

The value of charFitted should be set to the number of chars it could fit within the size its give (I'm giving it a size based on the point I am trying to hit test).

This works fine until the area is large enough to hold the 'test' string. at this point charFitted jumps from 3 ('tes') to 8 ('test    '). It basically always includes all the whitespace regardless of the space it has been give.

I've tried messing around with the StringFormat settings, but nothing seems t help...

I've included a test app bellow that demonstrates this

[image]
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            trackBar1.Maximum = this.ClientRectangle.Width;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            string sample = "abc                       def";
            int charFitted, linesFilled;

            e.Graphics.DrawString(sample, this.Font, Brushes.Black, PointF.Empty);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, trackBar1.Value, 0, trackBar1.Value, 100);

            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap | StringFormatFlags.LineLimit);
            sf.Trimming = StringTrimming.Character;
            e.Graphics.MeasureString(sample, this.Font, new SizeF(trackBar1.Value, this.Font.Height), sf, out charFitted, out linesFilled);
            textBox1.Text = "[" + sample.Substring(0, charFitted) + "]";

            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.trackBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // trackBar1
            // 
            this.trackBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 184);
            this.trackBar1.Name = "trackBar1";
            this.trackBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(259, 45);
            this.trackBar1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.trackBar1.Scroll += new System.EventHandler(this.trackBar1_Scroll);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(22, 229);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(237, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.trackBar1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBar1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It was not meant for hit-testing, use Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges() instead.

Comment: I tried that but I would need to create a characterRange for each char, and it throw OverflowException if more than 32 character ranges are set.

Comment: Damn, it really is! More than 32 throw `OverflowException`.

Comment: Maybe you could replace all white spaces with an underscore to do the hit testing...

Comment: I'm not sure if you can assume a space and underscore take up the same space in all fonts. The best solution I have at the moment is to run the code as is, then if there are spaces at the end of the position I'm at start removing them measuring the string until it fits. Still not ideal!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the length of "abc" and "abc      " are the same. Since you don't print out the trailing spaces the graphical representation is the same.
I would add a character at the end and then measure the string and remove the length of the added character.

Swith your OnPaint to this and it seems to work:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        string sample = "abc                       def";

        e.Graphics.DrawString(sample, this.Font, Brushes.Black, PointF.Empty);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, trackBar1.Value, 0, trackBar1.Value, 100);

        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap | StringFormatFlags.LineLimit);
        sf.Trimming = StringTrimming.Character;

        var underscoreWidth = e.Graphics.MeasureString("_", this.Font).Width;

        for (int i = 0; i < sample.Length; i++) {
            var s = sample.Substring(0, i + 1) + "_";
            var size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(s, this.Font).Width - underscoreWidth;
            if (size > trackBar1.Value) {
                if (s.Length > 0) {
                    var ok = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 2);
                    textBox1.Text = "[" + ok + "]";
                    base.OnPaint(e);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        textBox1.Text = "[" + sample + "]";
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Really don't like this solution but so far its the only working solution I have. Its based on the solution from @FSDaniel, but I've noticed that the results from Graphics.MeasureString & Graphics.DrawString drift out even if you pass the same StringFormat to them.

The only consistent measuring I've managed to achive using the TextRenderer with the TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl flag set.

This is a nasty solution which could be improved a little (performance wise) by hunting for a result, i.e. start in the middle of the string if its too big try 3/4 of the string, if thats to small try 5/8 etc until you have a result.

This is far from the best solution, so if anyone has anything better, please post it!

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        string sample = "abc                       defXXXXXXXXXXXXiiiiiiiX";

        TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl | TextFormatFlags.SingleLine | TextFormatFlags.NoPrefix;

        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, sample, this.Font, Point.Empty, Color.Black, flags);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, trackBar1.Value, 0, trackBar1.Value, 100);

        string measuredString = sample;
        for (int i = 0; i < sample.Length; i++)
        {
            Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, sample.Substring(0, i+1), this.Font, new Size(10000000, 1000000), flags);
            if (size.Width > trackBar1.Value)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "[" + sample.Substring(0,i+1) + "]";
                break;
            }
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```