# How to perform hit testing on the position within in a string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi

I'm writing out a string using `Graphics.DrawString`, and need to get the char index within a string given the mouse position.

It would seem that this should be pretty straight forward, but I'm really struggling to find an approach that works.

I found `e.Graphics.MeasureString` which returns the number of chars it managed to write, but it has some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910320/measurestring-always-thinks-whitespace-will-fit).

The only working approach I have at the moment is measuring `a`, then `ab`, then `abc` until I go past my `x` position, but this is a terrible solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MeasureString always thinks whitespace will fit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910320/measurestring-always-thinks-whitespace-will-fit)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd144860(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/tips/844745/analyzing-text-with-directwrite-in-net-using-sharp

Comment: If there was a solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910320/measurestring-always-thinks-whitespace-will-fit that would solve, it but so far its unanswered.

Comment: @Sprotty did you tried my answer?

Comment: I tried the approach, but shelved it when I hit the 32 region limit. I figured the call was designed more for picking out hyperlink/hotspot words in a text string, not for use on every char. As a last resort this coupled with MeasureString would probably provide a solution that worked efficiently, but it would be a bit of mess.

Answer (score 0):

You can once calculate coordinates of rectangles which occupy each char in your string, when you write it. After that you can scan this list, to see if mouse coordinates are within this rectangles.

Comment: *Kerning* makes this impossible in general case. Letters are in fact overlaping: e.g. "Wa": "a" starts *before* "W" ends. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning

Answer (score 0):

As one comment told you, you may achieve this using [MeasureCharacterRanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges(v=vs.110).aspx). I must first say that i edited and deleted my previous answer because it would be too long. And second,all this code is adapted from [here](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2015/02/measure-character-positions-when-drawing-long-strings-in-c/).

This solution is far from being perfect, but it may lead you to achieve what you want. First we have a method that measures the characters of a string maximum 32 characters long:

```
// Measure the characters in a string with
// no more than 32 characters.
private List<RectangleF> MeasureCharactersInWord(
    Graphics gr, Font font, string text)
{
    List<RectangleF> result = new List<RectangleF>();

    using (StringFormat string_format = new StringFormat())
    {
        string_format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        string_format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        string_format.Trimming = StringTrimming.None;
        string_format.FormatFlags =
            StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;

        CharacterRange[] ranges = new CharacterRange[text.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            ranges[i] = new CharacterRange(i, 1);
        }
        string_format.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(ranges);

        RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(0, 0, 10000, 100);
        Region[] regions =
            gr.MeasureCharacterRanges(
                text, font, this.ClientRectangle,
                string_format);

        foreach (Region region in regions)
            result.Add(region.GetBounds(gr));
    }

    return result;
}
```

After this, we now need a method to measure the full string,no matter how long:

```
private List<RectangleF> MeasureCharacters(Graphics gr,Font font, int      
                                           posY,string text)
{
    List<RectangleF> results = new List<RectangleF>();

    // The X location for the next character.
    float x = 0;

    // Get the character sizes 31 characters at a time.
    for (int start = 0; start < text.Length; start += 32)
    {
        // Get the substring.
        int len = 32;
        if (start + len >= text.Length) len = text.Length - start;
        string substring = text.Substring(start, len);

        // Measure the characters.
        List<RectangleF> rects =
            MeasureCharactersInWord(gr, font, substring);

        // Remove lead-in for the first character.
        if (start == 0) x += rects[0].Left;

        // Save all but the last rectangle.
        for (int i = 0; i < rects.Count + 1 - 1; i++)
        {
            RectangleF new_rect = new RectangleF(
                x, posY,
                rects[i].Width, rects[i].Height);
            results.Add(new_rect);

            // Move to the next character's X position.
            x += rects[i].Width;
        }
    }

    // Return the results.
    return results;
}
```

This is the method that draws the string and stores all character positions in 2 lines:

```
List<List<RectangleF>> linesCharactersPositions = new List<List<RectangleF>>();
private void Form3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    linesCharactersPositions = new List<List<RectangleF>>();
    string[] lines = new string[] { "12345678  0234567890123456789012asdjkhfkjasdhfklhasdlkfjhlasdkjhfasdlfhlasdc",
                                        "vm,xv,cxznvrtrutyquiortorutoqwruyoiurweyoquitiqwrtiqwetryqweiufhsduafh" };
    Font f = new Font("Arial", 18);

    int lineY = 10;
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        DrawLongStringWithCharacterBounds(e.Graphics, line, new Font("Arial", 18), new PointF(10, lineY));
        linesCharactersPositions.Add(MeasureCharacters(e.Graphics, f,lineY, line));
        lineY += 20;
    }


}
```

Finally, the `MouseMove` event:

```
private void Form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    int characterCount = 0;
    foreach(var linePositions in linesCharactersPositions)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < linePositions.Count; i++)
        {
            if (linePositions[i].Contains(e.Location))
            {

                label1.Text = "Index: " + (i+characterCount);
            }
        }
        characterCount += linePositions.Count;
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, well its a solution, but I'm not sure its going to work in my use case as I often have a screen full of lines that are wrapped at 1024 chars so a screen full of those (even if they aren't all visible I still need to track there location so I know what to draw where) would be maybe 150k chars. I maybe able to reduce this a bit with changes to the drawing code but you may still have 30k visible chars on screen.

Comment: @Sprotty see my updated answer. It may still not fit exactly your case, but i'm sure you may probably adapt it. Hope it helps.

Comment: This works and is surprisingly fast even when the screens filled with chars, however the chars start to slip out of sync. I guess this is as blocks of 32 chars are being measured individually. 
The only way I've managed to get the measure and and draw in sync is to use TextRenderer.DrawText & TextRenderer.MeasureText with the TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl.