# How to calculate float value from string

Tags: c#, drawing, calculation

I don't know how to calculate float value from string

```
float x = 300.0F;
Dictionary<short, string> stringDict = new Dictionary<short, string>();
Dictionary<short, string> whiteSpace = new Dictionary<short, string>();

string row1 = new String(' ', 67);
whiteSpace.Add(1, row1);
stringDict.Add(1, rtBox.Substring(12, 31).Replace("\n", " "));

graphicsObj.DrawString(whiteSpace[i] + stringDict[i], drawFont, drawBrush, x, y, drawFormat);
```

Expected output would be :

```
graphicsObj.DrawString(stringDict[i], drawFont, drawBrush, x + whiteSpace[i] float lenght, y, drawFormat);
```

How can I calculate this float value so I can omit drawing whitespaces ?

EDIT 1: below code doesnt work, its not moving drawing in x axis.

```
for (short i = 1; i <= 28; i++)
{
     SizeF rowSize = graphicsObj.MeasureString(whiteSpace[i], drawFont);
     float widthRow = rowSize.Width;
     graphicsObj.DrawString(stringDict[i], drawFont, drawBrush, x + widthRow, y, drawFormat);
      y += 15.0F;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the example input value and the expected output?

Comment: Hello @ChetanRanpariya - input is string row1

Comment: You have a string which as 67 continuous space characters in it... what output do you expect?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thats the problem, i want to omit this step of drawing those 67 space character, i would like to calculate for how much i must move drawing base on those 67 characters, so i need to add this value to "x" which is float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate the size of the string, you can try with `MeasureString`, however, according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910320/measurestring-always-thinks-whitespace-will-fit) question, this will not work for a string with only empty spaces. As a workaround, you could try to add a character at the end of your empty string or simply replace the empty space for another character to get the measure, for example:

```
string row1 = new String(' ', 66) + "#";
SizeF rowSize = graphicsObj.MeasureString(row1, drawFront);
float width = rowSize.Width;
float height = rowSize.Height;
```

Comment: "x + rowSize", operand + cannot be applied to Type SizeF and float

Comment: Check the update, you can get the width or the height from SizeF.

Comment: I will accept this answer, however it doesnt work for space character

Comment: its perfect, i did workaround and i wanted to updated my quesion with remark that Your solution works for other chars but it was rejected. Anyway Thank You very much for Your help all works perfectly :)